# initialize array of structs with const

Tags: arrays, c, struct, constants, typedef

```
typedef struct{     
  int nim;         
  float ipk;         
  char nama[50];         
  char alamat[50];     
} dataMahasiswa;

int main() {    
    dataMahasiswa p[MAX];
    
    p[0] = (const dataMahasiswa){120321004,4.00,"DAVID LEO","SURABAYA"};
    p[1] = (const dataMahasiswa){120321002,4.00,"HANIF AHSANI","NGANJUK"};
}
```

what is the meaning and function of const dataMahasiswa?

when I remove the `(const dataMahasiswa)` what happens is (error: expected expression before '{' token)

Comment: It's a C99 compound literal: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal

Comment: From a C point-of-view, `p[0] = (const dataMahasiswa){120321004,4.00,"DAVID LEO","SURABAYA"};` is not _initialization_.  It is _assignment_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because the compiler couldn't get the right `struct` (data type) to convert the given data. This feature was first introduced in C99 you should must read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

But, in `C++` you don't need to type the `struct` name before `{`, most of the modern `C++` compilers automatically does that.

Also, you don't need to write `const` before your `struct` name.

```
p[0] = (dataMahasiswa){120321004,4.00,"DAVID LEO","SURABAYA"};
p[1] = (dataMahasiswa){120321002,4.00,"HANIF AHSANI","NGANJUK"};
```

Comment: The question was not about C++, and I don't see any unnecessary "`struct`"

Comment: @aschepler That's just some extra points

Answer (score 2):

The qualifier const is redundant in the compound literals

```
p[0] = (const dataMahasiswa){120321004,4.00,"DAVID LEO","SURABAYA"};
p[1] = (const dataMahasiswa){120321002,4.00,"HANIF AHSANI","NGANJUK"};
```

You could just write

```
p[0] = (dataMahasiswa){120321004,4.00,"DAVID LEO","SURABAYA"};
p[1] = (dataMahasiswa){120321002,4.00,"HANIF AHSANI","NGANJUK"};
```

In this two statements compound literals are assigned to two elements of the array p.